# Iterate datarow in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

In Selected dataRow I have totally 200 data record rows. Now I need to divide the 200 records into 20  [10 times(for loop)]. so I use the take(20).It will take first 20 records.

I need to remove the first 20 records in last and need to choose another 20 records.I need to execute the 10 times for loop and get all the 200 records.

```
DataRow[] selectedDataRow = dtSMSDetails.Select("description = '" + smsDescription + "'");

if (selectedDataRow.Length > 0)
{
    string smsRecordId = "";
    string mobileNum = "";
    string smsSubject = "";

    foreach (DataRow rows in selectedDataRow.Take(20)) 
    {
        smsRecordId += rows["activityid"].ToString() + ",";
        smsSubject = rows["subject"].ToString();
        mobileNum += rows["telephone1"].ToString() + ",";
        // Here I need to remove the first 20 (take 20) records from the selected data row and need to loop next 20 records. 
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Skip(20).Take(20)` gets the next batch.

Comment: @stuartd It will skip the 1 - 20 records in first for loop and its take the 21 - 40 record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Skip()`

```
int startIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    foreach (DataRow rows in selectedDataRow.Skip(startIndex).Take(20))
    {
        smsRecordId += rows["activityid"].ToString() + ",";
        smsSubject = rows["subject"].ToString();
        mobileNum += rows["telephone1"].ToString() + ",";
    }

    startIndex += 20;
}
```

[Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: if i use like this it was skip the first 20 records in very first time and its take the 21 to 40 records

Comment: Updated my answer a bit. You need to store the amount you want to skip somewhere, in this case in variable `startIndex`.